# read certain number of lines from a txt file and convert to list in a pythonic way

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, idl-programming-language

Suppose I have the following txt file:

```
0.0163934
6
7.52438e+09
2147483648
6.3002e-06 6.31527e-08 0 0 6 0 0 4.68498e-06 0.00638412 12.6688
6.33438e-06 0 5.99588e-09 0 0 0 0 4.70195e-06 0 12.876
6.36874e-06 0 6.09398e-09 0 0 0 0 4.71894e-06 0 13.0867
6.40329e-06 0 6.19369e-09 0 0 0 0 4.73593e-06 0 13.3009
6.43802e-06 0 6.29503e-09 0 0 0 0 4.75294e-06 0 13.5185
6.47295e-06 0 6.39803e-09 0 0 0 0 4.76996e-06 0 13.7397
0.0163934
3
7.52438e+09
2147483648
6.3002e-06 0 5.89935e-09 0 0 0 0 4.68498e-06 0 12.6688
6.33438e-06 0 5.99588e-09 0 0 0 0 4.70195e-06 0 12.876
6.36874e-06 0 6.09398e-09 0 0 0 0 4.71894e-06 0 13.0867
```

I want to read each of the first lines as floats or integers and then depending on the second line I want to read the rest of lines as a list of lists or array.

In IDL language I just have to do:

```
openr, 1, fname
readf, 1, Time
readf, 1, Bins
readf, 1, dummy
readf, 1, dummyLong
da1= fltarr(10, Bins)
readf, 1, da1
```

So that the entire block of numbers is stored in the integer da1 which is size: 10*Bins. (rows and columns are the opposite as in python)

And then I can read the following lines in the same way.

In python I am doing:

```
Time=float(filen.readline())
Bins=int(filen.readline())
dummy=float(filen.readline())
dummyLong=long(filen.readline())

lines=[filen.readline() for i in range(Bins)]

arra=[[float(x) for x in lines[i].split()] for i in range(len(lines))]
```

So I need two lines of code and complicated iterations that are not understandable to a beginner.

Is there a way to do it like in IDL, in a single statement and pythonic?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh and I want to do it in a memory friendly way, since I actually have thousands of lines. That's why I don't use file.readlines()

Comment: `filen.readlines()` isn't memory friendly, but `for line in filen` is.

Answer (score 1):

One-liners are not necessarily better than two-liners.

But you can do it:

```
arra = [[float(x) for x in filen.readline().split()] for _ in range(Bins)]
```

I like it better in two lines:

```
lines = (filen.readline() for _ in range(Bins))
arra = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in lines]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will adopt this one, is quite compact.

Answer (score 1):

```
Time=float(fname.readline())
Bins=int(fname.readline())
dummy=float(fname.readline())
dummyLong=long(fname.readline())
arra = [ [ float(num) for num in line.split() ] for line in filen ]
```

That's just slightly more Pythonic, but it does not stop reading after the required number of lines, it simply reads them all. You could use `islice` from `itertools` in order to stop the iteration, or you could simply truncate the list afterwards.

Here's an example, and since I'm already using `islice` I took the liberty of getting all fancy with functional programming...

```
from itertools import islice

CONVERTORS = (float, int, float, long, )
with open(...) as filen:
    Time, Bins, dummy, dummyLong = [ func(value) for func, value in zip(CONVERTORS, islice(filen, 4)) ]
    arra = [ map(float, line.split()) for line in islice(filen, Bins) ]
```

Comment: This doesn't stop reading after the required number of lines.

Comment: @Tim: You're right, I added an explanation on how to stop reading as required.

Comment: Those itertools seem to be interesting, I will check which other applications it has.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more object-oriented way to do it using a simply coded FSM (Finite State Machine) to control the process of reading in complete data records. It's more verbose that the other answers currently posted, but it's a fairly flexible and extensible way to handle such tasks and do so with error-checking.

```
class Record(object):
    def __init__(self, time=None, bins=None, fltarr=None):
        self.time = time
        self.bins = bins
        self.fltarr = fltarr

    def read(self, file):
        """ Read complete record from file into self and return True,
            otherwise return False if EOF encountered """
        START, STOP, EOF = 0, -1, -99

        state = START
        while state not in (EOF, STOP):
            line = file.readline()
            if not line: state = EOF; break
            # process line depending on read state
            if state == 0:
                self.time = float(line)
                state = 1
            elif state == 1:
                self.bins = int(line)
                state = 2
            elif state in (2, 3):
                # ignore line
                state += 1
            elif state == 4:
                self.fltarr = []
                last_bin = self.bins-1
                for bin in xrange(self.bins):
                    self.fltarr.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])
                    if bin == last_bin: break
                    line = file.readline()
                    if not line: state = EOF; break
                if state != EOF:
                    state = STOP

        return state == STOP

    def __str__(self):
        result = 'Record(time={}, bins={}, fltarr=[\n'.format(self.time, self.bins)
        for floats in self.fltarr:
            result += '  {}\n'.format(floats)
        return result + '])'

fname = 'sample_data.txt'
with open(fname, 'r') as input:
    data = []
    while True:
        record = Record()
        if not record.read(input):
            break
        else:
            data.append(record)

for record in data:
    print record
```

Output:

```
Record(time=0.0163934, bins=6, fltarr=[
  [6.3002e-06, 6.31527e-08, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.68498e-06, 0.00638412, 12.6688]
  [6.33438e-06, 0.0, 5.99588e-09, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.70195e-06, 0.0, 12.876]
  [6.36874e-06, 0.0, 6.09398e-09, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.71894e-06, 0.0, 13.0867]
  [6.40329e-06, 0.0, 6.19369e-09, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.73593e-06, 0.0, 13.3009]
  [6.43802e-06, 0.0, 6.29503e-09, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.75294e-06, 0.0, 13.5185]
  [6.47295e-06, 0.0, 6.39803e-09, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.76996e-06, 0.0, 13.7397]
])
Record(time=0.0163934, bins=3, fltarr=[
  [6.3002e-06, 0.0, 5.89935e-09, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.68498e-06, 0.0, 12.6688]
  [6.33438e-06, 0.0, 5.99588e-09, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.70195e-06, 0.0, 12.876]
  [6.36874e-06, 0.0, 6.09398e-09, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.71894e-06, 0.0, 13.0867]
])
```

Comment: It is a really interesting solution. Indeed can be very useful for doing some checks and handling my data, i will keep it in mind, although in this case I need the code to be as compact and simple as possible, because other people have to read it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy loadtxt like

```
from numpy import loadtxt
data = loadtxt("input.txt", unpack=False)
```

then convert the data type as you wish like

Alternatively, readlines can also be used:

```
from numpy import fromstring
fin = open("filename.dat")
data = fin.readlines()
Bins = -3
for record range(no_of_records):
    i = record + 3 + Bins
    Time = float(data[i])
    Bins = int(data[i+1])
    dummy, dummylong = (float(data[i+2]),float(data[i+3]))
    Bins = [fromstring(data(i+4+j), dtype=float, sep=" ") for j in range(Bins)]
```